# Downloading music

Tags: terminal

if I download music from a legitimate website, like amazon or iTunes, and half through my download I receive a Facebook notification or a text message or phone call on my phone, will the notification sounds appear on the download song on playback, meaning I have to delete the song and redownload it, many thanks for any help

Comment: Thank you, so just to clarify things, if in the middle of downloading a song I receive Facebook notification sounds it won't appear on the song I downloaded on play back, just need to clarify I need to start downloading music to learn for a native American event and don't want lots of beeping sounds on playback

Answer (score 1):

No.  You're downloading a chunk of data from a server, and other activity on the device will not affect the content of that data.

It's the same as downloading something on your laptop.  The system sounds that your laptop plays do not affect your download of the Google Chrome installer or whatever.

As a imperfect analogy:  If I wanted to communicate a story to you, I could read it out loud while you copied it down.  In that case, things around the process would disturb it; talking, loud noises, that sort of thing.

The preferable way to communicate the story would be for me to just hand you a printed copy.  If I do that, we could be in the middle of a busy restaurant and you're going to receive the story without any problems.

iTunes/Amazon is handing your phone a copy of the song, not reading it out loud, and no matter how much Facebook or anyone else bangs on pans in the vicinity, none of that is going to affect the song that is being handed to your phone.

Comment: Thank you so just to clarify things, if in the middle of downloading a song I receive Facebook beeping notifications, they won't appear on the downloaded song on playback, I just need to clarify because I need to download and learn music for a Native American event

Comment: Assuming that you are downloading music as data, as through the iTunes store or the like, there is no link between sounds your phone makes and the data that is being downloaded.  At that level, all your phone is doing is downloading data.  There's no distinction between downloading data that happens to be a song, or an app, or an image, or whatever.

If the thing you fear were possible, then a Facebook notification that came up while you were downloading an app or an image would ruin that app or image.